# Is it possible to log systems memory and cpu usage using iis logs?

Tags: iis, iis-8, performance-monitor

I have a requirement to motiror what was the CPU usage and memory usage of the system when perticular request came.

Is it possible using IIS logs or any other method/tool to do so?

We dont want the usage of IIS process we want the usage of whole system at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows performance monitor to record cpu and memory usage (using data collector sets). Then, you can check in your IIS logs at what time the request in question came in and look up the recorded data in the performance monitor data collector set.

I don't think there is a tool which automatically combines the IIS log with system performance data. There are tools which include IIS monitoring, but those usually won't break reports down to a single request. If you want to do some further research you can use my [list of 40 windows server performance monitoring tools](https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools) as a starting point.

Comment: Yes you understood my issue correctly and approach is also fine, but the issue is that using performance monitor we can get the data for each second and in IIS we are logging records in milliseconds. So I am not able to get it on perticular milisecond. It works fine if I have to do it at second level.

Comment: do you have real world scripts samples about it? for automation